# trigger to update row number

Tags: mysql, mariadb, trigger, count

I have a MariaDB table

```
id | key  | year | .... | position        
1  | key1 | 2004 | ... |  3   
2  | key1 | 2011 | ... |  2  
3  | key1 | 2017 | ... |  1    
4  | key2 | 1994 | ... |  2 
5  | key2 | 2004 | ... |  1    
6  | key3 | 2004 | ... |  1    
7  | key4 | 1980 | ... |  2 
8  | key4 | 2011 | ... |  1
```

Position is the row number within they Key field order by year descending

How can I create a trigger to autofill position when I insert, delete or update any row. thanks

Comment: I currently doing in select with  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key  ORDER BY year desc, id desc ) as xposition   but  I have to do it each time

Comment: @jork, true but is that a problem? If you have 100 key_x and delete the first one you will have to update 99 additional rows

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL8.0, you could drop the column position, and create a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW view_amariadbtable AS 
SELECT 
  id, 
  `key`, 
  year, 
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY year DESC,id DESC) as position 
FROM amariadbtable
```

BTW, you should NOT use [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) as column name (`key`)